# Let $A$ be a set, $R$ an empty relation on $A$, what is $A/R$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $A=\{0,1,2\}$ be a set and $R=\{\}$. I know that $R$ is not an equivalence relation, but does it have to be? What is $A/R$ if $R$ is empty?

Examples:

$R_1=\{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)\}$, $A/R_1=\{[0], [1], [2]\}$

$R_2=\{(0,0),(1,1),(0,1),(2,2)\}$, $A/R_2\{[0, 1], [2]\}$

$R=\{\}$, $A/R=?$

Comment: How do you define $A/R$?

Comment: What means empty relation? can you define this?

Comment: Equivalence Classes, @Tobias, under $R$

Comment: @amWhy But that only makes sense for an equivalence relation.

Comment: So standard definition of quotienting a set by a relation is defined only for equivalence relations? Is that right?

Comment: I think if this makes sense then $A/R=\{\}$

Comment: @DavidToth Well, what does that definition say?

Comment: Notice that if you extend $R$ to the smallest equivalence relation $\hat R$ containing $R$, then $A/\hat R=A$ regarded as a subset of $\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: @user1 well, it can canonically be identified with $A$. It is actually the set of singletons of elements of $A$

Comment: Thank you. I think these comments contain the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is not an equivalence relation, so $A/R$ does not make sense with the standard definition.

The extension suggested by user1 would probably be the most sensible in general: we can define $A/R$ to be $A/S$ where $S$ is the smallest equivalence relation containing $R$. In case of $R=\emptyset$ it would be the equality relation, so $A/R=\{\{a\}\mid a\in A\}$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the classes of $A/R$ form a partition of the set $A$ i.e. a set of disjoint **non empty** sets which their union is $A$ but if $R$ is the empty set speak of a partition does not make sense so $A/R$ does not exist.

Comment: Why does it not make sense to speak of a partition of $A$ just because $R$ is the empty set?

Comment: Yes but I try to give another point of view to justify this.

Comment: That does not actually answer my question.

Comment: By definition a partition of a set is a collection of disjoint non empty set isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Why can $A/R$ not do this when $R$ is empty?

Comment: Can you find a partition of $A$ with use of the relation $R$? I think that the answer in no.

Comment: What do you mean by "with use of"? I agree that the quotient is not well-defined when $R$ is empty. In fact, it is not well-defined unless $R$ is an equivalence relation. I am disagreeing with your arguments for this.